# Nginx and pagespeed installation issues in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, server, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have put my app (implemented a website with the help of angularjs) on amazon EC2 and have installed nginx and thin on it

I am having issues with angularjs with respect to performance.

So I decide to install Pagespeed with recommendation of my seniors.

I am following the steps from [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/build_ngx_pagespeed_from_source) and [here](https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed).

However I am stuck with

```
./configure --add-module=$HOME/ngx_pagespeed-release-1.7.30.3-beta
```

I don't know the meaning of `./configure`. I don't have such a file or directory in nginx path.

I had installed nginx before so I skipped the part where we have to install nginx server.
Also I have installed the pagespeed module in root directory and nginx on `/etc/nginx`.

Is this why it is giving me issues and how do I solve this. Do I need to reinstall Nginx?

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "pagespeed module", did you mean the source code? `nginx` does not have a notion of dynamically loadable modules. Every module you enable is added to the main executable (`/usr/sbin/nginx`).

`configure` is a script in the source distribution of nginx, you won't find it anywhere on your filesystem unless you downloaded it. Remove your existing nginx binary and proceed with the mentioned instructions. Note that you are then fully responsible for any (security) updates.

Comment: Thanks for the help..I have written a lot of rules for nginx.conf ..Hence will cause problems if i have to delete it.Also is there any other kind of tool which i can use for similar effect.ie similar to pagespeed..

Comment: @Workforce It sounds you do not have a backup of your configuration. You should fix that first. Once you install the newer version of nginx, you can add the new configuration as needed. If you remove nginx without `--purge` option, then the configuration is also retained. Profile where your performance issue resides (server, client, network, ...) and try to fix the real problem instead of random guessing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want nginx-pagespeed support use following repository

```
add-apt-repository -y ppa:rtcamp/nginx
apt-get update && apt-get install nginx-custom
```

Refer: https://launchpad.net/~rtcamp/+archive/ubuntu/nginx/+packages